# Auto update publish date of CPT Post if default post custom field value match to cpt post CF Value

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, customization, custom-field

My question is - I have a CPT Post name Company (CF Value - Google) and a Page titled Role (CF V - Engineer). So I want to auto-update with Post published time and date to **company post** and **Role page** if published post custom field value match to Google and Engineer.

For example -

- A Job Post published at 11:30:21PM, 13/09/2021, has two Custom Fields Title Company and Role which has Google and Engineer values.
- Already published CPT Post Company has a post **Google Jobs** which has similar CF values Google.
- Similarly already published page **Engineer Jobs** which has CF value Engineer.

So my all condition is satisfied because CF value matched, now the code should update Engineer Job (Page), Google Jobs (Post) date and time with recent published post date, time.

Any reference code or help will be appreciated, I want to implement code in my **functions.php** file.

My Code (Not Working)

```
function my_cron_schedules($schedules){
    if(!isset($schedules["5min"])){
        $schedules["5min"] = array(
            'interval' => 1*60,
            'display' => __('Once every 5 minutes'));
    }
    if(!isset($schedules["30min"])){
        $schedules["30min"] = array(
            'interval' => 30*60,
            'display' => __('Once every 30 minutes'));
    }
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter('cron_schedules','my_cron_schedules');
wp_schedule_event(time(), '5min', 'my_hourly_event', $args);

//add_action('init','my_hourly_event');
function my_hourly_event() {
    $the_query = get_posts( 'post_type=post' ); 
    foreach($the_query as $single_post) {
        $id=$single_post->ID;
        $ad_close_date=get_post_meta($id, 'Validdate', true );
        if($ad_close_date!=''){
            $today=date("j F Y");
            if($ad_close_date<$today){
                $update_post = array(
                'ID'            => $id,
                'meta_key' => 'Location',
                'publish_date'  =>  get_the_time( '', $post->ID ),
                'post_type' =>  'jobs',
                'meta_value' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Location',true));
                wp_update_post($update_post);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using hook on update post meta for post update date.
Something like code below, just change the `company_title_meta` and `company_role_meta` to your correct meta key.

*If something does not work, send a comment and I will try to help you*

```
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'on_post_update_after_post_meta', 10, 4 );

function on_post_update_after_post_meta( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value )
{
    if ( in_array($meta_key, ['company_title_meta','company_role_meta']) ){
        $time = time();
        $my_post = array(
            'ID'            => $post_id,
            'post_date'     => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $time ),
            'post_date_gmt' => gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $time ),
        );
        wp_update_post( $my_post );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but not working, I have nothing changed in my previous code and add you new code. Changed `company_title_meta` -> Company and `company_role_meta` -> Role. I want to update the published date where the condition is satisfied. Didn't want to update custom field value or any meta.